# Illegal Key Size using AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding and Spongycastle on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes, spongycastle

Attempting 256 bit AES crypto on Android Studio. Developed a unit test to run using Android Studio 3.0.1. JDK does have the upgraded local and USExport policy files. Same code is used for 128 bit AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding, and works without error. Key generation, encrypt and decrypt all work fine with 128 bit key strength. Code for 256 is identical other than the length of the key. Also note, same code, using Bouncycastle, works under Netbeans with same JDK with policy files. Something about the Android/Studio platform and/or spongycastle. Baffled.

```
Results:
-----
Setting up unit test
Generating Keys
Provider before is: BouncyCastle Security Provider v1.58
Provider before is: SUN (DSA key/parameter generation; DSA signing; SHA-1, MD5 digests; SecureRandom; X.509 certificates; JKS & DKS keystores; PKIX CertPathValidator; PKIX CertPathBuilder; LDAP, Collection CertStores, JavaPolicy Policy; JavaLoginConfig Configuration)
Provider before is: Sun RSA signature provider
Provider before is: Sun Elliptic Curve provider (EC, ECDSA, ECDH)
Provider before is: Sun JSSE provider(PKCS12, SunX509/PKIX key/trust factories, SSLv3/TLSv1/TLSv1.1/TLSv1.2)
Provider before is: SunJCE Provider (implements RSA, DES, Triple DES, AES, Blowfish, ARCFOUR, RC2, PBE, Diffie-Hellman, HMAC)
Provider before is: Sun (Kerberos v5, SPNEGO)
Provider before is: Sun SASL provider(implements client mechanisms for: DIGEST-MD5, GSSAPI, EXTERNAL, PLAIN, CRAM-MD5, NTLM; server mechanisms for: DIGEST-MD5, GSSAPI, CRAM-MD5, NTLM)
Provider before is: XMLDSig (DOM XMLSignatureFactory; DOM KeyInfoFactory; C14N 1.0, C14N 1.1, Exclusive C14N, Base64, Enveloped, XPath, XPath2, XSLT TransformServices)
Provider before is: Sun PC/SC provider
Provider before is: Apple Provider
128 bit key = 6777d5f0e5f8a3c7956bba10fbb097e0
256 bit key = 5be06c6f944c8e52c7e5ab47f428b3f86ea493f190eba3cf3182dfc2b7c40ae
Provider after is: BouncyCastle Security Provider v1.58
Provider after is: SUN (DSA key/parameter generation; DSA signing; SHA-1, MD5 digests; SecureRandom; X.509 certificates; JKS & DKS keystores; PKIX CertPathValidator; PKIX CertPathBuilder; LDAP, Collection CertStores, JavaPolicy Policy; JavaLoginConfig Configuration)
Provider after is: Sun RSA signature provider
Provider after is: Sun Elliptic Curve provider (EC, ECDSA, ECDH)
Provider after is: Sun JSSE provider(PKCS12, SunX509/PKIX key/trust factories, SSLv3/TLSv1/TLSv1.1/TLSv1.2)
Provider after is: SunJCE Provider (implements RSA, DES, Triple DES, AES, Blowfish, ARCFOUR, RC2, PBE, Diffie-Hellman, HMAC)
Provider after is: Sun (Kerberos v5, SPNEGO)
Provider after is: Sun SASL provider(implements client mechanisms for: DIGEST-MD5, GSSAPI, EXTERNAL, PLAIN, CRAM-MD5, NTLM; server mechanisms for: DIGEST-MD5, GSSAPI, CRAM-MD5, NTLM)
Provider after is: XMLDSig (DOM XMLSignatureFactory; DOM KeyInfoFactory; C14N 1.0, C14N 1.1, Exclusive C14N, Base64, Enveloped, XPath, XPath2, XSLT TransformServices)
Provider after is: Sun PC/SC provider
Provider after is: Apple Provider
-----
-------------------------------- starting unit test 256 bit encrypt
encrypting with provider: BouncyCastle Security Provider v1.58
encrypting with key: 5be06c6f944c8e52c7e5ab47f428b3f86ea493f190eba3cf3182dfc2b7c40ae
encrypting with algorithm AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
encrypting with IV: afabc722d4105cba8125684871e6c47f
----- unit test failure caused by: 

java.lang.AssertionError: Illegal key size

    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at com.okanii.global.service.AbstractServiceUnitTest.failOnThrowable(AbstractServiceUnitTest.java:60)
    at com.okanii.global.service.SpongycastleSymmetricCryptoServiceTest.test256BitEncryption(SpongycastleSymmetricCryptoServiceTest.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)

java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1039)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1393)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1327)
    at com.okanii.global.service.provider.spongycastle.SpongycastleSymmetricCryptoProvider.encrypt(SpongycastleSymmetricCryptoProvider.java:154)
    at com.okanii.global.service.SymmetricCryptoService.encrypt(SymmetricCryptoService.java:85)
    at com.okanii.global.service.SpongycastleSymmetricCryptoServiceTest.test256BitEncryption(SpongycastleSymmetricCryptoServiceTest.java:159)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: The fact that you getting this error means you are *not* using the Unlimited jurisdiction crypto policy files. There's no use arguing you are, because the error says otherwise. You will have to do some investigating to find out which JRE is being used for your unit test. Also, why would an Android unit test be running on the Oracle Java platform?

Comment: Android Studio on MacOSX, using embedded JDK... found the JDK and policy files - limited and unlimited - upgraded the policy files for unlimited and restarted Studio. No joy still, though.

Comment: You didn't find *the* JDK, you found *a* JDK. OSx hides them in one place, brew hides them in another, your IDE install may install its very own JDK/JRE.